# Can't set footer to bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<div id="login-frame" class="frame-container">
<h2>Dash</h2>
<p>Wellcome</p>
 <hr>
<div class="alert hidden"></div>
<div class="frame-content">

<div class="row">
  <div id="appuntamenti_futuri" class="command-buttons tile col-xs-6 btn">
  <b class="title">Appuntamenti futuri</b>
  </div>
  <div id="storico_appuntamenti" class="command-buttons tile col-xs-6 btn">
   <b class="title">Storico</b>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="prenotazioni" class="command-buttons tile col-xs-12 btn">
  <b class="title">Prenota</b>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="card" class="command-buttons tile col-xs-6 btn">
  <b class="title">Card</b>
  </div>
  <div id="prepagate" class="command-buttons tile col-xs-6 btn">
    <b class="title">Abbonamento prepagate</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="frame-footer">
  <span style="color: #FFFFFF">Developed by</span>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
                Someone
  </a> 
 <span id="select-language" class="label label-warning">
                    Language
 </span>
 </div>

</div>
```

and this is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16139/)

how you can see the footer isn't on the bottom but there is a blank line after it, I set the background of the body for show you the problem. What I did wrong?

Comment: I don't see any blank-line? Or do you mean to have a fixed footer that always sticks to the bottom of the screen no matter how much content there is in the body?

Comment: sorry I have update the jsfiddle, anyway, yes I want the footer fixed on the bottom of the div

Comment: Alright, check my answer if that's what you mean

Comment: @Sandokan do you mind checking if the answer I provided helps you or not?

Comment: I commented the answer 'cause the problem isn't solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set any footer element to the bottom you need to use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`. Please read this article **[about Position in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)** for a complete reference.

Using `position: relative` on your desired footer element's parent will ensure that your footer element, which now has `position: absolute`, is relative to its parent. Immediately after, using `bottom: 0` on your footer element will shove it straight to the bottom of the screen. From there on, you can set its width to `width: 100%` and that will create the absolute basic layout of a footer.

Finally it goes without saying, ensure that your `html` and `body` elements cover the entire screen, so that your footer is positioned truly at the bottom of the screen. I wrote a very simple example (some sort of template) here:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.my-page-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.my-bottom-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**In conclusion**, applying the above comments to your code yields the following **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AGE/pmwbfzw2/1)**.

Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT**

Based on my above JSFiddle and the comments below, we have concluded that all was needed was for the footer element to sit directly beneath the `login-frame` element, for which I removed `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`. The relevant part of the problem, which was the `border-top` property within the footer element, is all that had to be removed from the code. This can be seen in the updated **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AGE/pmwbfzw2)**.

Comment: I don't know, it was not me, anyway, your solution is interesting but not working for me

Comment: @Sandokan that's ok, so how is this not working for you, explain the **what** to me so I can help

Comment: I have update your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/pmwbfzw2/3/, how you can see the login frame have now a white background, which I want is that the footer must be at the end of the white div, so login frame, not at the end of the page.

Comment: @Sandokan if I understand correctly, your footer must be directly below the login frame (white div) right?

Comment: Yes! @Age +1 for the will

Comment: In that case, remove `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` from the footer element, see what happens and if that is not what you need then let me know

Comment: @Sandokan will edit my answer based on our comments, make sure you **understand** why this works, otherwise I can explain

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to do something similar ages ago. try this as a css class on your div

```
bottom:36px;
position:fixed;
z-index:150;
_position:absolute;
_top:expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollTop+
    (document.documentElement.clientHeight-this.offsetHeight)));
height:30px;
width:500px;
margin-left:205px;
background:#efefef;
color:#000000;
overflow:auto;
```

Comment: bottom would = 0px not 36px

Comment: _“i wanted to do something similar ages ago”_ – yeah, that shows in the code. It should have been _buried_ ages ago as well. (F.e. `expression` has terrible bad performance …)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding you correctly but this should be what you want:

```
#frame-footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}
```

Comment: Nope, I want that the footer must be fixed to the bottom position of the parent div. I don't know if I was clear but, the footer is inside a div simply I want fit the footer to the bottom of this div.

Comment: The footer IS at the bottom of the div called 'login-frame'. If you for some reason still want to have it fixed just add position:fixed; width:100%; to #frame-footer